# Using String Formatting to pull data from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting

How do I use string formatting to call information from a dictionary?

Here's what I attempted so far (probably quite bad...)

```
value = raw_input("Indicate a number: ")
print number_stats["chm%"] % (value,)
```

The dictionary number_stats holds information about values "chm1", "chm2", etc.

I get a key error, which confuses me because the item chm1 is definitely stored in my dictionary.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print number_stats["chm%s" % (value)]
```

should work.

But you should do this instead:

```
print number_stats.get("chm%s" % (value), "some_default_value")
```

To avoid crashing if the user enters an invalid key. See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for more info on the `get` method.

Comment: You're welcome. See BrenBarn's answer for a better explanation of what was wrong with your initial code, and some more tips on using dictionnaries. Also, depending on what you're doing exactly or your preferences, there might be other ways to safely retrieve your value, using .get just turns out to be the most common one.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `number_stats["chm%"] % (value,)`, you are doing `number_stats["chm%"]` first and then applying `% (value,)` to the result.  What you want is to apply the `%` directly to the string:

```
number_stats["chm%s" % (value,)]
```

Note that you need `%s`; `%` by itself is not a valid string substitution.

However, there is probably a better way to do it.  Why does your dictionary have keys like `"chm1"` and `"chm2"` instead of just having the numbers be the keys themselves (i.e., have keys 1 and 2)?  Then you could just do `number_stats[value]`.  (Or if you read `value` from `raw_input` you'd need `number_stats[int(value)]`

Comment: Thanks! this was a very helpful explanation of what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Use like this. You have to use string formatting inside square brackets

```
>>> number_stats={'a1': 1}
>>>
>>> print number_stats['a%s' % 1]
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use the string `format` method...

```
value = input("Indicate a number: ")
print number_stats["chm{}".format(value)]
```